# Keep popup within window bounds

Tags: c#, wpf, popup

I'm trying to display a popup under a button.

This is what it looks like now :

[image]
But I want it to stay within the window borders, something like this (example in paint)

[image]

This is my top bar with the popup declared at the bottom:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="55" />
        <RowDefinition Height="35" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid x:Name="AdminContainer" Grid.Row="0">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="4*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="10" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Border Background="Transparent">
            <Viewbox StretchDirection="DownOnly" Stretch="Uniform" Height="35" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,0,0,0">
                <ContentControl Content="{StaticResource LynxLogo}" Margin="0,5" />
            </Viewbox>
        </Border>

        <ToggleButton x:Name="AdminOptionsToggleButton" 
                      Grid.Column="2" 
                      VerticalAlignment="Center"
                      HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                      IsChecked="{Binding mainViewModel.OptionsPopupOpen, Mode=TwoWay}"
                      Style="{StaticResource EmptyToggleButtonStyle}"
                      Cursor="Hand">

            <Grid x:Name="AdminPanel" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="45"
                  VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,0,2,0" >
                <Grid.Style>
                    <Style>
                        <Setter Property="Grid.Background" Value="Transparent"/>
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ToggleButton}, Path=IsMouseOver}" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Grid.Background" Value="#FF404040"/>
                            </DataTrigger>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ToggleButton}, Path=IsChecked}" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Grid.Background" Value="#FF353535"/>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </Grid.Style>

                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="45" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>


                <Border Grid.Column="0" Padding="20,0,0,0">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                        <!--Name-->
                        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding adminViewModel.Name}"
                                   Style="{StaticResource AdminTextBlockStyle}" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                                   FontSize="16" />
                        <!--Status-->
                        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding adminViewModel.StatusDescription}"
                                   Style="{StaticResource AdminTextBlockStyle}" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                                   FontSize="13" Margin="0,0,0,1" />
                    </Grid>
                </Border>

                <Border Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="3">
                    <Viewbox StretchDirection="DownOnly">
                        <Image x:Name="ProfilePicture" Source="/Image/ProfilePictures/profile_placeholder.png" />
                    </Viewbox>
                </Border>
            </Grid>
        </ToggleButton>
    </Grid>

    <views:OptionPopup x:Name="OptionsMenu" PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=AdminPanel}"
                       Placement="Bottom" 
                       MinWidth="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=AdminPanel}"
                       MaxWidth="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=AdminContainer}" />
```

Comment: Though it will take a [good bit of reading](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613596(v=vs.110).aspx) and trial and error I believe you can achieve this by setting the `HorizontalOffset`.

Comment: By giving the 'PlacementTarget' popup will not move out of the screen bounds.. This is an inbuilt function in wpf.. Is the popup moves out of current window or out of screen?

Answer (score 5):

I fixed it by setting the placement the custom:

```
<views:OptionPopup x:Name="OptionsMenuPopup"
     PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=AdminPanel}"
     Placement="Custom"
     MinWidth="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=AdminPanel}"
     MaxWidth="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=AdminContainer}" />
```

And in the constructor of my usercontrol in code behind I added

```
OptionsMenuPopup.CustomPopupPlacementCallback += (Size popupSize, Size targetSize, Point offset) =>
            new[] { new CustomPopupPlacement() { Point = new Point(targetSize.Width - popupSize.Width, targetSize.Height) } };
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a combination of SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight and the top-left point of the Popup to calculate how much room you have, and set that as the MaxHeight and MaxWidth of the Popup's contents.