# How to keep Popup in Application window wpf

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, user-interface, caliburn

I have been trying to have a popup whenever I press a button.
However. Lets say that I have a lot of text on that popup and then it can go over the application window bounds.

How I can I tell the popup to keep within the application window bounds in xaml code?

It would be great with some examples in xaml code on how to tell the Popup element to keep within the application

Thanks

Xaml code:

```
...
    <ToggleButton Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Margin="0,4"
        x:Name="Somethingname"
        Height="30"
        Template="{StaticResource ComboBoxToggleButton}"
        Content="Hello man"/>
    <Popup Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" x:Name="PopupMe"
            Style="{StaticResource PopupStyle}"
            ClipToBounds="True">

            <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding SomeObservableCollection}"
                      Width="{Binding ElementName=DetaljerHjemmmelToggler, Path=ActualWidth}"
                      ItemTemplate="{StaticResource SomeTemplate}"
                      cal:Message.Attach="[Event SelectedItemChanged] = [Action TreeView_SelectedItem($this, $source)]">

             </TreeView>
    </Popup>
    ...
```

In ResourceDictionary XAML file:

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="SomeTemplate" ItemsSource="{Binding ChildrenCollection}">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=TekstBlaaah}" Style="{StaticResource Label}"/>
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Popup}" x:Key="PopupStyle">
    <Setter Property="IsOpen" Value="{Binding ElementName=Somethingname, Path=IsChecked}"/>
    <Setter Property="AllowsTransparency" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="PlacementTarget" Value="{Binding ElementName=Somethingname}"/>
    <Setter Property="PopupAnimation" Value="Slide"/>
    <Setter Property="StaysOpen" Value="False" />
    <Setter Property="Placement" Value="Bottom"/>
</Style>
```

Comment: Ok, fine could you please include the xaml code for popup with your question?

Comment: this might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21431463/keep-popup-within-window-bounds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check it out:

[Custom popup and windows in WPF the MVVM way](http://blog.typps.com/2011/04/custom-popup-and-windows-in-wpf-mvvm.html)

Sample is also available

Comment: Thanks. It seems that using a part of the ModalDialog works. just not all of it since I have used it before and it was quite buggy :( (thanks bro! :D)